# Make dummy variables for a categorial variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable, dummy-data

Let's say I have a data frame `df` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("A","B","AB","O","O","B","A"))
```

Obviously there are 4 kinds of `type`. However, in my actual data, I don't know how many kinds are in a column `type`. The number of dummy variables should be one less than the number of kinds in `type`. In this example, number of dummy variables should be 3. My expected output looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("A","B","AB","O","O","B","A"),
                 A = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1),
                 B = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0),
                 AB = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0))
```

Here I used `A`, `B` and `AB` as dummy variables, but whatever I choose from `type` doesn't matter. Even if I don't know the values of `type` and the number of kinds, I somehow want to make it as dummy variables.

Comment: R regression function deal with the dummy coding automagically. Just create a factor variable and and the magic will be there when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The number of dummy variables should be one less than the number of kinds in `type`.

> Here I used "A", "B" and "AB" as dummy variables, but whatever I choose from `type` doesn't matter.

> Even if I don't know the values in `type` and the number of kinds, I somehow want to make it as dummy variables.

This is treatment contrasts coding. First, you need a factor variable.

```
## option 1: if you care the order of dummy variables
## the 1st level is not in dummy variables
## I do this to match your example output with "A", "B" and "AB"
f <- factor(df$type, levels = c("O", "A", "B", "AB"))

## option 2: if you don't care, then let R automatically order levels
f <- factor(df$type)
```

Now, apply treatment contrasts coding.

```
## option 1 (recommended): using contr.treatment()
m <- contr.treatment(nlevels(f))[f, ]

## option 2 (less efficient): using model.matrix()
m <- model.matrix(~ f)[, -1]
```

Finally you want to have nice row/column names for readability.

```
dimnames(m) <- list(1:length(f), levels(f)[-1])
```

The resulting `m` looks like:

```
#   A  B  AB
#1  1  0   0
#2  0  1   0
#3  0  0   1
#4  0  0   0
#5  0  0   0
#6  0  1   0
#7  1  0   0
```

This is a matrix. If you want a data frame, do `data.frame(m)`.

Comment: Is there any other method if I don't want to use `O` as a dummy variable? You suggested ```f <- factor(df$type, levels = c("O", "A", "B", "AB"))```  . But what if there are so many kinds of `type` so that I cannot write the whole values of `type` ? I want to know how to state explicitly that I don't want to use `O` as a dummy variable.

Comment: @Bae How about `f <- relevel(f, ref = "O")`, after `f <- factor(df$type)`.